# Как настраивать размеры и положение Dialog в LibGdx

Tags: java, разработка-игр, libgdx, mobile

Что я не делаю, но кроме метода `ScaleX()` `ScaleY` и т.д. ничто не работает.

Какие цифры я не ввожу в параметры в `setPosition` или `setSize`  - ничего не меняется.

Answer (score 0):

В **libGDX**, прежде чем динамически менять состояние `Actor` после создания, необходимо вызвать метод `actor.setTransform(true);`.

Без этого состояние будет обновляться только в моменты лейаута, насколько я помню.
Попробуйте `setTransform()`, если не поможет, то нужно будет смотреть код.